# Why does HoltWinters() in R behave differently when parameters are set as 0 vs set as False?

Tags: r, time-series

Why is it that the `HoltWinters` function in R gives *vastly*  different parameter estimates, say of `alpha` and `beta`, when `gamma` is set as `0` versus set as `False`? It would seem from the structure of the model the 2 should be specifying equivalent models?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No, these are completely different models. First, I recall 0<`gamma`<1, hence you shouldn't be able to fit `gamma`=0 anyway [Edit: This might be only the case for the multiplicative version]. Second, if you set `gamma` to FALSE you fit a Holt Winters Model *without* a seasonal component (doubly exponential smoothing). If you set `gamma` to zero, you fit a triple exponential smoothing model where the seasonal change smoothing parameter is zero (hence the actual value $x_t-s_t$ at time $t$ gets a 0 weight and the seasonal correction factor gets a weight of 1, i.e. $c_t=c_{t-L}$ for all $t$; see https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Holt-Winters#Triple_exponential_smoothing).